# Cyclic Vector Spaces and Endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to show that :

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$, let $T : V \rightarrow V $ be an endomorphism of V, and let $n = \dim_K(V )$.

Suppose that there exists an integer $m ≥ 0$ and a vector v such that $V$ is equal to the T-cyclic, i.e. V = <$v, T(v), ... T^m(v)$> (the powers of T), then $B = $ {$v, T(v), ...,  T^{n-1}(v)$} is a basis of V.

Thoughts: I know that the number of elements in {$v, T(v), ...,  T^{m}(v)$}  $\geq |B|$ so that a shortened or equal number of elements of the former set will be a basis of V, but what I find confusing is that if $m \geq n$, then why is it necessarily false that there can be linearly dependent vectors for some $T^j$ where $j \leq n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement follows easily from the [Cayley-Hamilton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), which states:

> **Theorem.** Let $p(x) := \det(x\,\text{id}-T)$ be the characteristic equation of $T$. Then $p(T) = 0.$

The characteristic equation is a polynomial of degree $n$,
$$p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_nx^n.$$
Notice that in fact $a_n = 1$. Therefore, we can write $T^n$ as a linear combination of $\text{id},T,\ldots,T^{n-1}$. It follows that $T^kv$ is in the span of $B$ if $k\ge n$.

Comment: I will research this theorem, I have not yet learned it. In the meantime can you verify if my answer is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesDickens You might try to take a look at this very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/403078/60713

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that for some $0 < i < j \leq n-1$ where $ i \neq j$ that
$T^j = T^i$, then $T^{j-i} = 0(v) = 0_{V}$ for all $v \in V$, then since $j-i < n$, for any $k > j-i$,  $T^k = T^{k-(j-i)}T^{j-i} = 0$, thus there could be a maximum of $j-i-1$ linearly independent powers of T. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: This is not enough. Indeed, we could have $T^j\neq T^i$ but $T^jv = T^iv$, or just some linear dependence.